# How to update bundled SQLite library (or driver?) in V10 for OS X

Tags: databaselink, databases

I've been using undocumented `Database` functions with Mathematica V9 to acces my SQLite database, which is a Firefox-generated database that contains cookies.

```
db = Database`OpenDatabase[
  "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/sjk6e588.default/cookies.sqlite"];
Database`QueryDatabase[db, "SELECT sqlite_version();"]
```

> {{"3.8.6"}}

In order for this to work, I had to manually replace the outdated `libsqlite3.dylib`, which is located at

```
/Applications/Mathematica9.app/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/libsqlite3.dylib
```

otherwise Mathematica could not read the database. Now in V10 the undocumented `Database` functions no longer work, but instead there are new functions available to work with databases. The new code looks like this:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
db = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite",
  "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/sjk6e588.default/cookies.sqlite"]];
SQLExecute[db, "SELECT sqlite_version();"]
```

> {{"3.6.23.1"}}

As you can see the bundled SQLite library is still outdated and does not work with this database. I tried replacing the `libsqlite3.dylib` file, which is now located at

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Libraries/MacOSX-x86-64/libsqlite3.0.dylib
```

but Mathematica apparently ignores it and still uses the outdated library.

How can I update the SQLite library (or driver) so I can work with this database?

Comment: `OpenSQLConnection` and `SQLExecute` have been around, and documented extensively, for several versions. As for the driver issue it might be something you need to ask Wolfram tech support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica 10 ships with version 3.7.2 of the [Xerial SQLite JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc). Let me first verify your findings.

```
SQLiteVersion[] := Module[{v, c = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite(Memory)", ""]]},
    v = First@First@SQLExecute[c, "SELECT sqlite_version();"];
    CloseSQLConnection[c];
    v
];
SQLiteVersion[]
```

> 3.6.23.1

There are a few SQLite databases in that profiles directory:

```
$dir = "/Users/dillont/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/2bd5ni53.default";
    dbs = FileNames[{"*.sqlite"}, $dir];
dbNames = FileBaseName /@ dbs
```

> {"addons", "content-prefs", "cookies", "extensions", "formhistory", "healthreport", "permissions", "places", "signons", "webappsstore"}

Try opening connections to each of these:

```
connAssoc = AssociationThread[dbNames, OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite", #]] & /@ dbs];
readable = SQLConnectionUsableQ[#, {"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';",
    {{_String} ..}}] & /@ connAssoc
```

> <|addons->True,content-prefs->True,cookies->False,extensions->True,formhistory->True,healthreport->False,permissions->True,places->False,signons->True,webappsstore->False|>

Four of them don't work (including the cookies database). Probably they were added to the application more recently. Note here I've used the two-argument form of `SQLConnectionUsableQ` to supply my own test. This is because the newer database will happily answer older drivers issuing the trivial query used by the default test (typically something like `SELECT 1`), but it won't actually let you look at any tables.

I'll close these connections and then try the newer driver.

```
CloseSQLConnection /@ Keys[connAssoc];
```

The procedure here will be like adding a driver for any unbundled database, like Oracle ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseConnections.html); see especially the section on JDBC Connections). The short version is, I'm going to download a jar and put it on the classpath.

[A new release of the SQLite JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads) dropped a few hours before this writing. There are a bunch of places I could put it; a reasonable choice is `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/SQLite/Java/`. I do that.

I can now restart my Mathematica session, or just restart Java:

```
<< JLink`;
ReinstallJava[];
```

If you wear a belt and suspenders, verify that the new driver is taking precedence over the old one on the classpath:

```
Flatten@StringCases[JavaClassPath[], ___ ~~ "sqlite" ~~ ___]
```

> {"/Users/dillont/Library/Mathematica/Applications/SQLite/Java/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar", 
>   "/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/DatabaseLink/Java/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"}

And the version should have incremented:

```
SQLiteVersion[]
```

> 3.8.6

The installation looks good. Try opening and testing the connections again:

```
connAssoc = AssociationThread[dbNames, OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite", #]] & /@ dbs];
readable = SQLConnectionUsableQ[#, {"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';",
    {{_String} ..}}] & /@ connAssoc
```

> <|addons->True,content-prefs->True,cookies->True,extensions->True,
>   formhistory->True,healthreport->True,permissions->True,places->True,
>   signons->True,webappsstore->True|>

Better. Try getting some data out of the cookies database:

```
SQLTables[connAssoc["cookies"]]
```

> {SQLTable[moz_cookies, TableType->TABLE]}

```
SQLColumns[connAssoc["cookies"], "moz_cookies"][[All, 1]][[All, -1]]
```

> {id,baseDomain,appId,inBrowserElement,name,value,host,path,expiry,lastAccessed,
>   creationTime,isSecure,isHttpOnly}

```
SQLSelect[connAssoc["cookies"], "moz_cookies", {"id", "baseDomain", "name", "value", "expiry"}, "MaxRows"->5, "ShowColumnHeadings"->True]
```

> {{id,baseDomain,name,value,expiry},{95,imrworldwide.com,V5,AStfNzpEBSg7EhozMRwjIyotCRsYAVInHlJJJQ__,1424978712},{96,imrworldwide.com,IMRID,US0MGYpsGysAACYAtzc,1424978712},{100,thedailybeast.com,_lsd0,17bbb925-5480-41e3-bd6c-f402972b2903,1514834714},{102,erovinmo.com,_lsx0,3f60d7b6-804a-11e2-865d-d3726fca0c4b,1519673114},{103,wunderground.com,DT,1361906715:18788:365-v5,1577836799}}

```
CloseSQLConnection /@ Keys[connAssoc];
```

Comment: Thanks, everything works except the penultimate `SQLSelect` command, which gives me an error "JDBC::error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: id) >>". Nevertheless, I can read the cookie database with these instructions, so I will accept your answer.

Comment: My typo; edited.